# Printer status using Ip and Port Number iphone sdk

Tags: objective-c, ios4, printing, ip-address, port-number

Can anyone please help how to findout the print status of a printer using printer's Ip address and port Number.Using SNMP, Please help me..

Comment: Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: I found the solution: http://xander.xjmaas.nl/Xanders_Apps/Mobile_SNMP++.html